# ARM NEON improvements in Eigen 3.3

Tags: c++, arm, eigen, neon

I am using Eigen C++ library to write certain algorithm for 64-bit ARM Cortex-A53 processor.

It says in the Eigen changelog (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.3) 
that there are ARM NEON improvements in release 3.3, including "correct tuning of the target number of vector registers." Now, does anybody know what does this actually mean? Is it possible to tell Eigen to take full advantage of the 32 vector registers of A53? According to my quick tests it didn't happen automatically.

Thanks, Lauri

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the report... technically, you found a bug!

Eigen should tune its usage of NEON 128-bit registers to that in arm64 mode, it uses 32 of them. I thought that I had made it do that, but it looks like I was wrong :-/
https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/tip/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h?fileviewer=file-view-default#PacketMath.h-34

One should fix that...

Comment: That said, I now remember what this changelog entry was referring to: the situation before Eigen 3.3 was even worse, as that constant was set to 8 ! At least now it uses 16, which is the correct value for arm32.

Comment: Fixed on default branch: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/1095dd392946a44a260ef0f4c2a0c32e696bd8e0, and on 3.3 branch: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/9498b5b4c39d452452cceef90d88d6f9b4f19d62 . Note that just because this setting is now fixed, does not automatically know that Eigen will know how to make a good use of the additional registers for a particular operation.

Comment: Thanks Benoit. My code has two critical parts. 1) multiplication of large matrices and 2) computing eigenvectors with SelfAdjointEigenSolver. 
Eigen release 3.3 (without your fix) gives nice speed-up for part 2). I inherited your fix and added #define EIGEN_ARCH_ARM64 1 to further speed-up 1) or 2), but I didn't get any improvement (compared to 3.3 without your fix). Does this sound like expected behavior or could there be more bugs?

Comment: I think what is happening here is that Eigen does not have a wider GEMM kernel to use, than the one it has for the 16 registers of ARM32. So it effectively does not know how to make use of the additional registers, even though it now knows that there are additional registers. Feel free to bring this up on Eigen's bugzilla or mailing list. That said, in my own experimentation, I have found that there was only limited room for further speeding up such GEMM kernels by using more registers, that is, the existing Eigen GEMM is already close to as fast as a generic ARM kernel will get.

Comment: If you want to get more substantial speedups specifically for the Cortex-A53 core, consider departing from generic code like Eigen. Here is a study of various kernels, including a float kernel optimized specifically for Cortex-A53 by ARM engineers. It performs much better than generic code on this particular CPU, but be aware that it is counter-productive on other CPUs. https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/standalone/neon-gemm-kernel-benchmark.cc#L2257